# iPhone Changing TabBar on-the-fly?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I'm quite new in iPhone Programming, but I'm trying to do my best cause I have some skills in OOP.

I'm creating an iPhone app based on a four element Tabbar. I would like to use other functionalities already implemented by a friend of mine in his own iPhone app (a three elements TabBar app). 
Since I would like my app's users could "switch" to old application (3 tabs) by pressing on one of my app's tab, my question is: is it possible to do this, maybe by "popping out my tabbar" (4 tabs) and "pushing in the old tabbar" (3 tabs)?

For a better problem description, we could say that I'm trying to implement a "new mode" and "old mode" in the same application.

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I'm using Xcode 3.2.2 on a Macbook Pro coreDuo and 3.1.3 iPhone simulator

Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little bit vague, but if you want to be able to choose between two different tab bars, the easiest way to do it is to include *both* tab bars in the application, and simply hide the one you don't want active. You can still do this in Interface Builder. Just wire up both tab bars, and let your view controller hide the old one in `-viewDidLoad`. Then, when the "old mode" button is pressed, show the old tab bar and hide the new one.

Comment: Sorry for the delay...I was dealing with other application issues....I'll try to use your solution and I'll let you know.
Thank you in advance.